# How to attach data property along with Json Object generated through WebService?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I am generating Json object using the Webservice in asp.net. I have successfully generated this Json Object but I want this object to be displayed along with the data property attached to it.

**My Webservice**

```
[WebMethod]
    public void GetEmployees()
    {
        string CONStrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constrng"].ConnectionString;
        //We are now using List Array by creating List of Employee Object
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        //Creating SQLConnection
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONStrng))
        {
            //Build SQLCommand object for executing the storedprocedure
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetEmployee", con);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 50;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //Looping through each rows
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //create employee class object and populate all its properties
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]);
                employee.FirstName = dr["firstname"].ToString();
                employee.LastName = dr["lastname"].ToString();
                employee.SSN = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ssn"]);
                employee.DEPARTMENT = dr["department"].ToString();
                employee.AGE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["age"]);
                employee.Salary = dr["salary"].ToString();
                employee.MartialStatus = dr["maritalstatus"].ToString();
                employee.Address = dr["address"].ToString();
                //Now add the employee object to the List object we created at first
                employees.Add(employee);
            }
        }
        //Now pass this list to the serialize method of the javascriptserializer class which is going to serialize the list of employees object to a json array
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(new { data = employees }));
    }
```

**This is how my Json Object Looks-**

```
[
    {"ID":1,"FirstName":"Ashish","LastName":"Kumar","SSN":111,"DEPARTMENT":"IT","AGE":25,"Salary":"18000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Garia"},
    {"ID":2,"FirstName":"Abhishek","LastName":"Kumar","SSN":112,"DEPARTMENT":"IT","AGE":26,"Salary":"18000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Garia"}
]
```

**But I want the Json Objects to be displayed as-**

```
{
    "data": [
        {"ID":1,"FirstName":"Ashish","LastName":"Kumar","SSN":111,"DEPARTMENT":"IT","AGE":25,"Salary":"18000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Garia"},
        {"ID":2,"FirstName":"Abhishek","LastName":"Kumar","SSN":112,"DEPARTMENT":"IT","AGE":26,"Salary":"18000","MartialStatus":"Single","Address":"Garia"}
    ]
}
```

Please guide me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
js.Serialize(new { data = employees })
```

Or you can create a separate class for that. Just be careful with casing if you really want `data` property to be in lowercase/camelcase and employee properties in titlecase.

Do you also have some reason to use `JavaScriptSerializer`? There are much better alternatives for JSON serialization.

Comment: I have already tried this but still I am not able to attach data property along with the json object I am getting.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code where you are trying to add `data` property.

Comment: Please check my question. I have already mentioned it in my question. I have mentioned how my json objects looks and I want it to appear along with "data".

Comment: Can you save the result of `js.Serialize(new { data = employees })` in string variable? Then check in debugger which JSON you have.